# Get a value of aggregate function count() from datareader

Tags: c#, sql, datareader

Coding in C# and My query is,

```
query = "select COUNT(*) as rowsCount from employee_leaves where PARTY_ID ='10'";
```

After executing,

```
OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

How can I now get the count into the `int`

the table I get from the database has 1 row containing 3 as,

I have tried this, `int i = dr["rowsCount"];`

and this, `int i = dr.GetInt32(0);`

but didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only need to get one value, use `ExecuteScalar()`. Example

```
string sqlQuery = "select COUNT(*) as rowsCount from employee_leaves where PARTY_ID ='10'";
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
// other codes here such as opening the connection
int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you code in c#. Please use before `dr.Read()` (it should return true), then use dr to read values from first row.